# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE tab delimited text file syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm using the MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command to load a tab delimited text file. But when I include **the column list** I get an error code 1064.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myfile.txt'
        INTO TABLE mytable 
        (column1, column2, column3)
        FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 10 LINES;
```

The non-column version works:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myfile.txt'
        INTO TABLE mytable 
        FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 10 LINES;
```

What is causing the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being caused by the position of the column list, which should be in the last row, i.e.:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myfile.txt'
    INTO TABLE mytable 
    FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 10 LINES
    (column1, column2, column3);
```